# How to solve and plot differential equations in R

Tags: r, differential-equations, calculus

Taken from Sal Khan's lecture https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oiDvNs15tkE of the Khan academy, if I know that dN/dt=rN(1-(N/K)) (the logistic differential equation)

How can I solve for N and plot the N=f(t) with R?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This logistic equation has an analytical solution (see for example [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j_Taf2Tgggo)), so you can plot it directly. Another option is to solve it numerically using one of the available solvers (see [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/DifferentialEquations.html))

```
## Using the `deSolve` package
library(deSolve)

## Time
t <- seq(0, 100, 1)

## Initial population
N0 <- 10

## Parameter values
params <- list(r=0.1, K=1000)

## The logistic equation
fn <- function(t, N, params) with(params, list(r * N * (1 - N / K)))

## Solving and plotin the solution numerically
out <- ode(N0, t, fn, params)
plot(out, lwd=2, main="Logistic equation\nr=0.1, K=1000, N0=10")

## Ploting the analytical solution
with(params, lines(t, K * N0 * exp(r * t) / (K + N0 * (exp(r * t) - 1)), col=2, lwd=2))
```

[image]

Comment: haven't checked, but it's a little surprising that the analytical and numerical solutions are visibly different ...

Comment: If you find a problem please let me know (or edit).

Comment: Two problems: (1) you use `Y0` instead of `N0` in your analytical expression.  (2) in order for your analytical and numerical solutions to line up, you need to start the ODE solution from t=0 rather than t=1 (e.g. `t <- 0:100`)